# Travis-CI allow_failures when multiple environment variables are set

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to set `allow_failures` for a complex build process, but unfortunately it isn't working.

The problem is that in my `env` I am setting multiple environment variables, and cannot get Travis to recognise that I want on of these rows to be allowed to fail.

[The documentation on `allow_failures`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Rows-that-are-Allowed-to-Fail) shows how to allow a single `env` to fail, along with another configuration option, but doesn't cover how to allow a multiple enviroment variable setup to fail.

The troublesome sections of the `.travis.yml` file are below:

```
env:
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=sqlitefile   SEARCH=whoosh
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=postgres     SEARCH=whoosh
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=mysql        SEARCH=whoosh
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=sqlitefile   SEARCH=elasticsearch
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=postgres     SEARCH=elasticsearch
  - DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9' DB=mysql        SEARCH=elasticsearch

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9'  DB=mysql  SEARCH=elasticsearch
    - env: DJANGO_VERSION='1.8,<1.9'  DB=mysql  SEARCH=whoosh
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

Travis `allow_failure` options must be identical down to the whitespace!

So this won't work:

```
env:
  - FOO='one'      BAR='two'
  - FOO='three'    BAR='four'
matrix:
  allow_failures:
  - env: FOO='one' BAR='two'
```

But this will:

```
env:
  - FOO='one'      BAR='two'
  - FOO='three'    BAR='four'
matrix:
  allow_failures:
  - env: FOO='one'      BAR='two'
```